# best way to define a unordered_map of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Is it the same in term of performance to define a `std::unordered_map` like this

```
unordered_map<int, std::vector<ClassA>>
```

and like this?

```
unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::vector<ClassA>>>
```

for the `std::vector<ClassA>` part, I am using `std::move` anyway.

Comment: In the end you will have to measure this with a realistic use-case and your definition of "performance". There is no general answer to this. Each version may be "performant" at some things, and less so at others.

Comment: The nice thing about `unique_ptr` is that it forces `move`s or does not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that the `unordered_map` never moves/copies its nodes, they should be equally fast in terms of complexity. But keep in mind that

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<ClassA>>
```

has one less indirection when you want to access the vector's data:

```
std::unordered_map -> [node -> std::vector] -> data
```

where the internal node probably *contains* the vector. OTOH:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::vector<ClassA>>>
```

results in

```
std::unordered_map -> [node -> std::unique_ptr] -> std::vector -> data
```

where now the node contains only the `std::unique_ptr` which needs to be actually dereferenced to reach the `std::vector`.

Comment: when you say node, do mean like a pointer? is it right that the map just contain the pair of key and location of the actual value? And the map will not be slow down when the vector expend?

Comment: @BryanFok Yes, it's about pointers and internal subobjects of the `unordered_map`. The size of any type (including `std::unordered_map`) in C++ is a fixed value, hence the `std::unordered` instance contains pointers to dynamically allocated memory where it stores data. These structures will then need to contain or allocate space for the data members.

Comment: @BryanFok Please also note juanchopanza's comment on your Q and that I carefully avoided to mention which version is "better" in my answer. The additional indirection might be slower *or* faster, depending on your use case. Especially with multi-threaded applications cache-locality, etc. can have a strange influence so the only real advice is: Measure! With my answer I was just trying to point out where the differences in performance could result from so you get a better understanding of the effects you will see.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question can be stated differently and splitted in two part:

- Internaly, when the `std::unordered_map<>` will copy and not move ?
- Whan inserting/retrieving an element from a `std::unordered_map<>` is there always a way to avoid copy ?

For the first part of the question, the answer is no. There is not even a move invoked during rehash (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664295/does-unordered-map-copy-release-contained-objects-if-there-is-insert-remove-reha)). You can be sure that if you inserted/retrieved your elements without copying, there will be no copy.

Now, for the second part of the question.

Every time you `insert`, `emplace`, or use `operator[]` for assignment there is an overload with the rvalue reference, but you have to ensure that your code will allow the use of such a thing. Avoid: `my_map[index] = my_vector;` or even `my_map.insert(std::make_pair(index, my_vector));` because that will not call the rvalue ref oveload. Either use `std::move`or pass directly a rvalue, or use initializer lists.

Now, when retrieving the data, with iterators or using for loop, there should be no problem as long as you use references on your element, e.g.:

```
for (auto& my_element: my_map) { ... }
```

and not:

```
for (auto my_element: my_map) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, awesome explanation on how to use the map properly in overall.